# I want to make a random numbers and letters generator, but this will not work

Tags: python, ascii, pyautogui

> ```
> import random, string, pyautogui, time
> numbers=random.randint(1000000000, 1000000000000)
> def random_char(y):
>        return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(y))
>
> time.sleep(2)
> pyautogui.typewrite(random_char(10))
> time.sleep(0.5)
> pyautogui.write(numbers)
> ```

output = piTPLlrXPn (<--- Random 10 Letters)

but numbers won't work

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'int' object is not iterable
  File "C:\Users\Noah\Pictures\Python\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    pyautogui.write(numbers)
```

EDIT: Works Now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: The name `numbers` implies it should be a list, but `random.randint` returns an integer. Also, are you sure you don't want `random.randrange`?

Comment: It seems that `pyautogui.write(numbers)` expects an iterable. You could convert the number to a string.

Comment: Do you actually want a random number, or do you want a 10-character string consisting entirely of numerical digits?

Comment: Ints are not iterable, however strings are, so if you convert your int (variable named number in this case) to string you should be able to get what you want

Comment: Replace `numbers` with `str(numbers)` on the last line, if that's what is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyautogui.write() expects a iterable object, ints are not iterable but strings are so in this case you just need to call,

```
pyautogui.write(str(numbers))
```

And that should write the random number you got at the start of your code.

However you could do something similar to what you are doing with ascii characters giving a list of int characters or you could extend the list of ascii characters with numbers if you want a result with letters and numbers

Answer (score 0):

the integer has limited range and the range you entered is quite large and out of range. try smaller values like, 1000,10000